# Calling overridden method from super Class itself

Tags: swift, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

I have following setup:

```
class Human {
    init() {
        eat()
    }
    
    func eat() {
        print("I eat edible stuff")
    }
}
```

```
class Vegan: Human {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    override func eat() {
        print("No meat or dairy!!")
    }
}
```

Now when I create instance of `Vegan()` then it actually calls `eat()` of `Vegan` and not `Human`.

```
let _ = Vegan()

Output:
"No meat or dairy!!"    // How? Black magic? it should be "I eat edible stuff" right?
```

How is this possible? Since call to `Human`'s `init()` goes via `super` shouldn't everything inside of Human's init block get executed on its own context? How it knows and called overrided method? I believed child's implementation gets changed, this is something weird.

Comment: `Human's init block get executed on its own context?` How did you arrive on this conclusion? If you put a break point in `Human`'s init block and try to print `self` it clearly mentions as `Vegan` not `Human`, so it is very much aware of the context that `self` is still `Vegan` and `Human` is just the parent class.

Comment: In fact if you put this if condition `if self is Vegan { print("Am inside because am Vegan though control is in Human") }` in `Human`'s init, print statement will be displayed on console, thats because condition `self is Vegan` passes through when control is in `Human`'s init thats because swift run time knows that the actual init was called from `Vegan` though currently its in `Human` class self is still `Vegan`, thats why when you call `eat` on `self` `Vegan`'s eat gets called and in your function overriding you havent called `super.eat` hence parent class (Human) eat is not called

Comment: When you override superclass and instantiate the subclass then the superclass is part of that created object, it’s not a separate object. And anything that the subclass overrides is what is being used when accessing that object, the only way to access the overridden method in the superclass is to explicitly use `super`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very relevant question, as different languages have different semantics.

In C++ a `Vegan` object would be constructed by first constructing a `Human` object.  Any member function called in that constructor, would be dispatched to the `Human`'s function. Then only would the `Vegan` part be constructed.

Swift uses a different approach.  In this regard, it is important to keep in mind that Swift uses the term [initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) instead of construction. The idea is that if you create a `Vegan` you get from the beginning a `Vegan` object that doesn't eat meat, even during the initialization process.

Swift makes this relatively safe, with its constraints regarding the two step initialization.  Let's add some initialized variables to the class;  You'll see that the swift compiler will make sure that everything **must** be initialized in due time to avoid any risk of initialized variable:

```
class Human {
    var id: Int
    
    init() {
        id = 0    // all variables must be intialized before calling a function
        eat()
    }
    
    func eat() {
        print("I eat edible stuff")
    }
}
class Vegan: Human {
    var message: String
    
    override init() {
         message = "hello"  // must be initialized before calling super constructor. 
         super.init()
    }
    
    override func eat() {
        print("No meat or dairy!!")
    }
}
```

Of course, if you use some member functions to ensure invariants that are more complex than variable initialization,  it's up to you to take extra-care about those invariants.